# ¿Por qué «pastuso» y no «pasteño» para la gente de Pasto, Colombia?

Tags: colombia, gentilicio

Tenemos estos gentilicios:

- Quito => quiteño
- Cuzco => cuzqueño
- Pasto => pastuso

Me gustaría saber por qué para Pasto se usa «**pastuso**» en vez de «pasteño».

¿Hay algunas reglas del idioma castellano que determinen cómo debería terminar la palabra para describir los habitantes de una ciudad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como explican en [este artículo](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-41033285) un gentilicio suele venir desde a partir de diversos sufijos y del lugar en cuestión. Además, se puede fijar de manera oficial (lo determina un estado, ciudad o autoridad legitima) o se genera a un nivel popular.

Ahora, el sufijo *-uso* suele utilizarse poco, como en *luso* (acortamiento de lusitano), *antuso* (de Antas, en España si bien no aparece en el DLE), *ruso* o *bielorruso*. Además, ten en cuenta que el nombre del municipio es San Juan de Pasto, lo que hace que el gentilicio venga como un [acortamiento](https://www.eltiempo.com/archivo/documento/CMS-4908948) (Al igual que Quito, lo que evita que sean *sanjuaneros*, *sanjuaneños* o *sanjuanenses*). Por último, existe también el gentilicio *pastense* con un uso minoritario.